# Parsing XML file in an Android application

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am creating an Android application. In that, I am showing the result by parsing an XML file that is stored in the [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital) of the mobile. But it is taking more than one minute to parse the XMl file.

So for this I have implemented the AsyncTask functionality, but still it is taking more than one min.

The same code, if I am running as a Java application for parsing the XML, is taking 3-5 seconds to parse the complete XML and printing the data.

**Parsing code**

```
public class ParseMyTripResponseXML {
    String aprovedStatus="";
    SetFlightRecordsData objFlight;
    public MyTripRespone parseMyTripXML(File filename) {
        MyTripRespone respObj = new MyTripRespone();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = null;

        CorporateBookingApprovals corpApprovalObj = null;
        List<CorporateBookingApprovals> corpApprovalList = new ArrayList<CorporateBookingApprovals>();

        try {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = dBuilder.parse(filename);
        }
        catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.d("SAXException", e.getMessage()+"");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("IOException", e.getMessage()+"");
        }

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        Node rootNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("Root").item(0);
        Element rootElement = (Element) rootNode;
        String status = getTagValue("StatusCode", rootElement);
        if (status.equals("200")) {
            NodeList corpList = ((Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("Result").item(0)).getElementsByTagName("CorporateBookingApprovals");
            for (int i = 0; i < corpList.getLength(); i++) {
                try {
                    Node corporateDetailsNode = corpList.item(i);
                    Element corporateDetailsElement = (Element) corporateDetailsNode;
                    corpApprovalObj = new CorporateBookingApprovals();
                    corpApprovalObj.setApprovalId(getTagValue("ApprovalId", corporateDetailsElement));
                    corpApprovalObj.setAgentId(getTagValue("AgentId", corporateDetailsElement));
                    String statusApproval  = getTagValue("ApprovalStatus", corporateDetailsElement);
                    if(statusApproval.equals("approved")){
                        aprovedStatus = "A";
                    }else if (statusApproval.equals("pending")) {
                        aprovedStatus = "P";
                    }
                    else if (statusApproval.equals("inqueue")) {
                        aprovedStatus = "Q";
                    }
                    else if (statusApproval.equals("rejected")) {
                        aprovedStatus = "R";
                    }
                    corpApprovalObj.setApprovalStatus(aprovedStatus);
                    corpApprovalObj.setInsertTime(getTagValue("InsertTime", corporateDetailsElement));
                    objFlight = new SetFlightRecordsData();
                    objFlight.setFlightData(doc, corpApprovalObj);
                    corpApprovalList.add(corpApprovalObj);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("exception in main", e.getMessage()+"");
                    continue;
                }
            }
            respObj.setCoroprateBookingDetails(corpApprovalList);
        }

        return respObj;
    }

    public static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
        NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
                .getChildNodes();
        Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
        if (nValue == null) {

            return "";
        }
        else {
            return nValue.getNodeValue();
        }
    }
```

How do I make it faster?

I am using the DOM parser.

Comment: Post your code to parse the XML.

Comment: Are you check the same procedure in some other devices as well. Because this depend on device capability as well.

Comment: How big is the XML file? Bear in mind that despite the fact that mobile devices are getting closer to desktop computers both in RAM size and CPU speeds, they are still quite slow. I am no expert in this, but meybe if the file is big enough Android will not be able to load it whole into memory (but desktop computer would) - if so then sequential file IO operations will hog your performance. All in all, there are quite a few other factors to be consider other than code optimization (which is important as well).

Comment: @Losiowaty the size of file is 1.06MB

Comment: I'm using XmlPullParser library to fully parse/traverse a 600KB file, on the order of 40ms.

Comment: You could have a look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html. A tutorial for the same http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/xml/android-simple-xml-sax-parser-tutorial/. See if this is any faster.

Comment: @S.A.NortonStanley i tried this also but no effect ...same issue i am facing

Comment: @LawrenceChoy waiting for u r comment

Comment: @Losiowaty u was very correct that was the issue.when  i loaded the file from classpath the parsing has been done in 15 secs ..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the general approach to speeding up your XML parse routine by adding timer functions and process of elimination, commenting out sections and rerunning it so you know exactly what is causing your slow down.  Usual suspects would be object creation calls and string handling.

```
long startTime;
long endTime;

startTime = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

// parse routine here

endTime = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

Log.d("xmlparse", "Excution time: "+(endTime-startTime)+" ms");
```